# Individual classes on PHP rows

Tags: php

I have the following thats within a loop...

```
 echo "<span class='srch-val'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
```

I want to somehow add a number or something after the class 'srch-val-1' without using jQuery, is this possible using PHP? If so where can I find out how to do this? thanks

Its currently within a foreach() loop...

```
 foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) { //Stuff }
```

Comment: What kind of loop (for(each), while...)? If your loop has a counter variable, you could just echo that `echo "<span class='srch-val-".$i."'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";`

Comment: What loop is it in? `foreach()`? `for()`?

Comment: I believe he is talking about a wordpress loop ... But I might be wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<span class="srch-val-'.$your_value.'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
```

$your_value can be everything you want , including a number..

A very simple loop example

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 echo '<span class="srch-val-'.$i.'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
}
```

will return

```
<span class="srch-val-1">
<span class="srch-val-2">
<span class="srch-val-3">
.... 10
```

or for example - in a wordpres loop , you can even do

```
echo '<span class="srch-val-'.$post->ID.'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
```

or

```
echo '<span class="srch-val-'.the_title().'">'.apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
```

and so on ... any available value can be applied . of course you then have to think how to TARGET an over changing class with CSS - but that is for another question,.

**EDIT I** - as for comment for the loop inside loop -  the above  was just a generic example - you need to put the counter in the beginning of your original loop and increment it on the end . (if it is a wordpress loop like i suspect, put $i=1 , or any other number , after the `if (have_posts())` or after the `while (have_posts())` -depending on where you need it - and the incrementing `$i=$i++` at the end. (before the `endif;` or `endwhile;` - again depending on your needs...)

Comment: Thankyou @Obmerk this works only it loops hundreds of times as its within another loop, is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
 echo "<span class='srch-val".$something."'>".apply_filters(" $value\n", $value)."</span>";
```

Where $something is a counter, custom text, whatever.

Comment: How would it work though @kernelM? When the page loads will something not be assigned a value and then stay the same?

Comment: Didn't you say this is inside a loop?